# Unity, android data folder empty

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I can't fix a problem with JSON files on an Android device.

In Unity Project - Assets, I created the "**StreamingAssets**" folder and inside there is a .json file (data.json).
Once the app is installed on my android device and going to the folder "**/storage/emulated/0/ Android/data//files**"
there is no json file that I put in the "StreamingAssets" folder. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you put at design time files in the assets folder then they become packed in the .apk file. They will not automatically be extracted and copied to device storage. They remain in the .apk. To access them you have to use the Assets Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I do to get the Languages text from `Language.json` file in `StreamingAssets`

```
IEnumerator LoadLocalizedText(Action<bool> success)
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Language.json");

        string dataAsJson = "";

        //Android
        if (filePath.Contains("://"))
        {

            WWW reader = new WWW(filePath);

            //Wait(Non blocking until download is done)
            while (!reader.isDone)
            {
                yield return null;
            }

            if (reader.text == null || reader.text == "")
            {
                success(false);

                //Just like return false
                yield break;
            }

            dataAsJson = reader.text;
        }

        //iOS
        else
        {
            dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        }


        jsonString = dataAsJson;

        if (dataAsJson == "") 
        {
            success(false);
            UpdateLanguage(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Language", "SP"));
        }

        else
        {
            success(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain the "Action <bool> success" line to me?
I try to insert it but it goes wrong, I'm definitely doing something wrong ...

Comment: Are you using "System" namespace? This is how I use this function:  


           StartCoroutine(LoadLocalizedText((status) =>
            {
                if (!status)
                {
                    //Failed to load file
                }
                else
                {
                    //Successfully Loaded File
                }

            }));


You can just pass `null` if you don't want to check or run any code after completion.